# octokit createPullRequest for JSON files

Tags: node.js, json, github-api, octokit-js

I have been trying to create a pull request using the **createPullRequest** plugin from **octokit** and so far for simple text files it works well, but when I am trying to commit some changes into a JSON file in the repository, I get something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXtaB.png]
<sup>ss from the pull request</sup>

I want this data to present itself in a json-structure, I am using the following code:

```
const updatedContent = JSON.stringify(json_for_package);
        const pr=await octokit_pull.createPullRequest({
            owner: ownername,
            repo: repoName,
            title: "pull request "+dependency,
            body: "change "+dependency+" v"+curr_version+" to v"+version,
            base: "main" ,
            head:  "pulls-requests-branches-names-main-"+dependency+"-v"+version,
            forceFork: true, 
            changes: [
            {
                files: {
                    "package.json": updatedContent,
                },
                commit:
                "updated the contents of package.json",
            },
            ],
        });
```

Here json_for_package is the JSON content that I want to write into my `package.json` file, I just need to know how I can pass the `updatedContent` in the files so that it recognizes that it a JSON file and not any simple text.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing the same problem can do the following- first writing the json data into a .json file and then read it to use it, seems to have worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Beside writing the JSON to a file first, and use the file as parameter, you can also use [`gr2m/octokit-plugin-create-pull-request`](https://github.com/gr2m/octokit-plugin-create-pull-request):

Example

```js
const MyOctokit = Octokit.plugin(createPullRequest);

const TOKEN = "secret123"; // create token at https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo
const octokit = new MyOctokit({
  auth: TOKEN,
});
```

And then:

```js
// Returns a normal Octokit PR response
// See https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#octokit-routes-pulls-create
octokit
  .createPullRequest({
    owner: "user-or-org-login",
    repo: "repo-name",
    title: "pull request title",
    body: "pull request description",
    base: "main" /* optional: defaults to default branch */,
    head: "pull-request-branch-name",
    forceFork: false /* optional: force creating fork even when user has write rights */,
    changes: [
      {
        /* optional: if `files` is not passed, an empty commit is created instead */
        files: {
          "path/to/file1.txt": "Content for file1",
          "path/to/file2.png": {
            content: "_base64_encoded_content_",
            encoding: "base64",
          },
          // deletes file if it exists,
          "path/to/file3.txt": null,
          // updates file based on current content
          "path/to/file4.txt": ({ exists, encoding, content }) => {
            // do not create the file if it does not exist
            if (!exists) return null;

            return Buffer.from(content, encoding)
              .toString("utf-8")
              .toUpperCase();
          },
          "path/to/file5.sh": {
            content: "echo Hello World",
            encoding: "utf-8",
            // one of the modes supported by the git tree object
            // https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#tree-object
            mode: "100755",
          },
        },
        commit:
          "creating file1.txt, file2.png, deleting file3.txt, updating file4.txt (if it exists), file5.sh",
      },
    ],
  })
  .then((pr) => console.log(pr.data.number));
```